# Add VBA code to all worksheets for ALL excel workbooks in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I searched but could not find any topics on this specific use case.

I have developed code that I want to implement on multiple (>100) different excel files and was wondering if there is a way using VBA or other to add the VBA code to ALL worksheets in ALL excel workbooks in a specific folder.

In addition,  I will need to enable Microsoft Internet Controls reference in all as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a disaster from an implementation & maintenance perspective, but it is possible using the Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility reference, which allows you to programmatically insert modules and manipulate code. [Here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) is a good primer which shows you how to do it. If you get stuck with specific implementation details, please revise your question to narrow its scope. As currently asked, it's "too broad" :)

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44466940/1467082) is an answer that also outlines basic function to add a code module. Instead, you'd need to refer to the sheet's specific module, but that is not a huge diversion from that answer already.

Comment: Thank you,  I will look into this solution and see if it works for my case.

Comment: do you really need to have the code in all those workbooks? could you have the code in one "master" workbook and have it interact with all those workbooks?

Comment: These are files on a cloud server that are constantly being accessed and modified so they have to work independently.